# How to cover an image with a grid (clickable squares) using HTML, CSS, and JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a floorplan like this:

[image: floorplna]

I need to cover specific areas with a grid (clickable squares) just like this:

[image]

So, as you can see I don't need to cover all the picture with grid. Only a few sections.

Also, I want the squares to be clickable as I want to be able to change the colour of the square using some JS.

Many topics on this but all of them cover the whole image with a grid. I need certain areas to be covered.

Can it be achieved with HTML, CSS and JS?

That's my code so far:

```css
.test {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 55%;
  height: 925px;
  top: 105px;
  left: 25px;
}
.img1 {
  z-index: 1;
}
.img2 {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <button class="switch btn btn-info col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" @click="addFurniture">{{ text }}</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div style="posiotion: relative;">
        <div class="img" id="floorplan">

          <div class="img1 imgSize">
              <img id="grid" src="../assets/floorplan.png" class="col-md-7 grid rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="floorplan">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <button class="test btn btn-success" style="position: absolute;">test</button>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="img2">
             <img v-if="!isHidden" src="../assets/furniture.png" alt="furniture" class="col-md-7 rounded mx-auto d-block">
          </div>
```

Comment: If you really just need squares, then you can just position a couple of links absolutely, above the image. If you work with percentages for the position and width/height of those clickable elements, the whole thing can even be “responsive” pretty much out of the box.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `<map>` element ([see on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)) to make some areas of the image clickable

Comment: My image is of a fixed size and it is positioned absolute. Wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: There is some non-responsive sizing in your CSS, the floor plan taking 55% of width but having a px height. Are you looking for an overall responsive solution? This would be fairly easy to achieve if it were not for this anomaly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the color of a picture with JS, you might only add some styles on it which would look more like a filter.

For grid, you can put on elements on top of the picture that are shaped as you wanted like in the picture, using `absolute` positioning. Then you do whatever you want.

As long as you don't turn the image into code, your options are limited in my opinion.

Comment: the part with the colours I will handle. Regarding the grid, you see the image is positioned as absolute. If I try to put on top a grid of divs, how then to make sure they are responsive for any screen size? Atm, the divs on top change they position while streching the screen.

Comment: If possible, could you add some code example?